# Getting error while using ' % '

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert following statement which is in JavaScript to C#,
But at one point I'm getting following error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'bool' ".
Could any one point me out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

```
//x offset for odd or even rows

If((row + rowoffset) % 2) {
    Debug.log(row+rowoffset);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript code please ?

Comment: The modulus operator returns the remainder, which is not true or false. True or false is required in if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# if statements requires your condition to be either true or false which is 1 or 0. the code you are using is entirely capable of producing a float.

Change your code something like below, this depends on what exactly your code does, but you can do this to just to check and make your changes appropriately

```
If((row + rowoffset) % 2 == 0){

Debug.log(row+rowoffset);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, zero equals false but not in C#:

you should write something like that :

```
if((row + rowoffset) % 2 == 1){
    Debug.log(row+rowoffset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing a modulo function on a floating point value will result in a floating point value, not a bool.  I believe this will do what you want:

`if((row + rowoffset) % 2 != 0){
    Debug.log(row+rowoffset);
}`

Comment: The selected answer actually inverts the logic of the test giving different results than the original code.  The check should be for != 0 or == 1 as given in the other two answers.